# Why is injecting a SecurityContext into a Jersey Singleton thread safe?

Tags: jersey, thread-safety

In the Jersey documentation, [Example 16.2](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/security.html#d0e12372) shows an example of injecting a SecurityContext into a Jersey resource singleton.

[image: Jersey Example 16.2]

Surely the docs are correct, and the example given is indeed thread safe.

I suspect that the injection of the SecurityContext happens exactly once, and when `getUserPrincipal()` is called, perhaps it picks up user data from some structure that is attached to the thread itself (maybe a ThreadLocal object?). That's the only way I can see that the correct user info be served to the end user when there are a ton of threads competing.

Can anyone confirm this behavior, or otherwise explain the thread safety of the Jersey example?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Dynamic Proxies](https://dzone.com/articles/java-dynamic-proxy) are used with a ThrealLocal backing. This is kinda explained in the JAX-RS spec, in regards to some request scoped injectable objects (See [this post for spec quote](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30592433/2587435))

> I suspect that the injection of the SecurityContext happens exactly once

Yes this is true, but what's injected is actually a *proxy*. You can print out the class name and you will see that it is actually a Proxy. The first link in this post explains how it works. When you call methods on the proxy, it delegate the calls to the thread local security context.

**See also:**

- [Dynamic Proxies and Dependency Injection](https://psamsotha.github.io/jersey/2015/12/16/dynamic-proxies-dependency-injection.html).