# Jersey 2 - Register response filter based on request header

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

I have two `ContainerResponseFilter` for a request method, of which only one should be run. This is decided based on a particular request header.

I created a `DynamicFeature` that checks this header and register the filter accordingly.

```
public class CustomFeature implements DynamicFeature {
    @Context
    HttpHeaders httpHeaders;

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceInfo resourceInfo, FeatureContext context) {
        String value = httpHeaders.getHeaderString("x-something"); 
        if (value != null && !value.isEmpty()) {
            context.register(SomeFilter.class);
        } else {
            context.register(OtherFilter.class);
        }
    }
}
```

This throws the following exception:

```
"java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not inside a request scope.
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.guava.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:169)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.current(RequestScope.java:153)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.inject.hk2.RequestContext.findOrCreate(RequestContext.java:55)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.MethodInterceptorImpl.internalInvoke(MethodInterceptorImpl.java:65)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.MethodInterceptorImpl.invoke(MethodInterceptorImpl.java:101)
    ...
```

I understand that the error is coming as during configuration, there is no request and hence no header. However this is where I am confused. As per [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30592433), `HttpHeaders` is proxieable. Therefore shouldn't a proxy be inserted here and delegated to actual instance when a request is being processed? (It seems this method of `@Context` injection works perfectly fine in `ContainerResponseFilter` and `ContainerRequestFilter` classes).

Also, how to run only one filter based on the header?

Comment: `configure()` is not called during a request. It's called at startup during configuration time. Only once. Whether it's a proxy or not doesn't matter, it's going to be called when there is no request.

Comment: @PaulSamsotha in this case can't we determine which filter to run and which to skip based on some request context?